# Using ListIterator on a custom LinkedList

Tags: java, listiterator

I have a custom, generic, singly LinkedList which I built myself. I can add, remove etc to the List just fine. I'd like to implement the Java ListIterator to my class. How would I go about starting this? What methods do I need to add to my class? All I can find on the web is examples of using the ListIterator on the default Java LinkedList which is no good to me. Thanks!

Comment: You can't implement `ListIterator` in a sane way on a singly linked list, since `ListIterator` requires support for reversed traversal and that's just not possible with a singly linked list!

Comment: @Joachim - it's definitely possible; just terribly inefficient. To go backwards, you just need to start at the beginning of the list and go forward until you reach the node that has the current node as its "next" element.

Comment: @Sean - he also said reversed traversal is "just not possible".

Comment: @Ted well technically that's true. It isn't possible, so you have to fake it.

Comment: @Sean - I think we have very different ideas of what "not possible" means. :-)

Comment: @Ted I agree Joachim's wording was bad, because reversed traversal can be faked by starting from the head. But you will have to agree that real reversed traversal is impossible.

Comment: @Sean Well, what do mean "real"? A hash table is a collection that can (more or less) directly retrieve a value given a key. Does this mean that an AVL tree can't do "real" retrieval because it has to start at the root and do a lot of navigation to get at the value for a particular key? Of course not. I see this as the same kind of thing: a characteristic of the data structure that makes reversed traversal inefficient.

Comment: @Ted: my wording might have been off, but: given (only) the last node of a singly-linked list, you **can't** traverse it backwards to the start (excluding cases like "single-node list"). That's my definition of "sane implementation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a second class (usually a nested class of your linked list) that implements all the functions of the ListIterator interface. Note that some functions (like `add` and `remove`) are optional—you can just throw an UnsupportedOperationException. Your linked list class needs to implement the methods `listIterator()` and `listIterator(int)` to return an instance of your second class.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the [Iterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) or the [ListIterator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) interface.

Comment: Well ListIterator interface according to his question, but yes you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the methods that ListIterator has. You will need to make sure that your version of it has those same methods.

If you can, look for an `Interface` that ListIterator uses, and implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a singly linked List, implementing `ListIterator` will be tricky (if not impossible), as it needs to navigate in both directions, which you can only implement by restarting from the head over and over again.

Either make your list double-linked, or you will have to throw `UnsupportedOperationException` on lots of methods. (Or live with O(n) performance in half the methods)

Comment: I don't think throwing an UnsupportedOperationException is a legitimate implementation of `previous()`; it's not one of the methods documented as optional. Also, why would a singly (forward-) linked list have O(n) performance for `next()`?

Comment: @Ted a) I know. That's why I'd say this can't be a valid implementation of java.util.List b) ok, you got me: 5 out of 9 methods will perform reasonably

Answer (score 0):

For performance, you can implement `ListIterator` and keep a "backwards" version of your list as you iterate through it. This would emulate a doubly-linked list, but only for the iterator.

However, it's probably safer to just implement your linked list as a doubly-linked list underneath.